# How to add an external header footer file (.xml format) to an existing .docx document using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, docx, cpu-word

Actually, I want to add an upper header to a document, but because the format of the document header is more demanding and standard, I want to try inserting the header file directly into the document. I think it would be better to reference it directly with a standard header file than to create a header from poi.

I have an xml type file with header, file name is 'headerExternal.xml', its contents are as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><w:hdr xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:jc w:val="left" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b />
                <w:color w:val="FF00FF" />
                <w:sz w:val="30" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t xml:space="preserve">page 1</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

I want to insert headerExternal.xml into a .docx file and follow the ooxml specification

The original .docx document：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyRVH.png)

The docx document after it has been inserted：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08fA9.png)

I tried use the hdrDocument provided by poi to resolve the headerExternal .xml file directly, as follows:

```java
HdrDocument hdrDocument = HdrDocument.Factory.parse(new File("headerExternal.xm"));
```

But I don't know how to bind this object to the XWPFDocument object,So I'm not making any progress at the moment.

I tried the methods provided by Axel Richter and found that they did solve my problem.

But I also found that adding a whole bunch of complete < w:hdr > tags to a document is really not a good idea because it causes the document to browse for the first time for the missing prompt style.

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. What shall be the reason and use for this `headerExternal.xml` being contained in the `*.docx` ZIP archive?

Comment: @AxelRichter Hello, thank you for reminding me that I have added in the topic. Actually, I just want to insert a header into the document, but because the header is so demanding, I think it's better to use a standard header file directly than to build a header with poi.

Comment: But that `headerExternal.xml` within the `*.docx` ZIP archive will never be used as a header in `Word`. It only will be a useless additional file in that ZIP archive. And it will be removed when `Word` saves the file the next time. There is no way around using `XWPFHeader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). One could put that `headerExternal.xml` into the `*.docx` ZIP archive using `OPCPackage`. But that `headerExternal.xml` within the `*.docx` ZIP archive will never be used as a header in `Word`. It only will be a useless additional file in that ZIP archive. And it will be removed when `Word` saves the file the next time. There is no way around using `XWPFHeader`.

But if you really wants using a `*.xml` file as template for the `XWPFHeader`, then this could be done using [XWPFHeaderFooter.setHeaderFooter(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr headerFooter)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeaderFooter.html#setHeaderFooter-org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr-). That needs a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr` which could be created from a `*.xml` file like so:

```
...
File headerContent = new File("./headerExternal.xml");

org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr ctHdrFtr =
 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.HdrDocument.Factory.parse(headerContent).getHdr();
...
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class DocxWordHeaderFromFile {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));

  File headerContent = new File("./headerExternal.xml");
  
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr ctHdrFtr = 
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.HdrDocument.Factory.parse(headerContent).getHdr();

  for (XWPFHeader header : document.getHeaderList()) {
   header.setHeaderFooter(ctHdrFtr);
  }
 
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordDocumentNew.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Axel Richter's answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434836/why-use-the-ctsectpr-factory-parse-method-to-parse-xml-labels-appear-nested-by-t), I found the answer I wanted

Recall my previous needs:

> I wanted to take out the `footer.xml` or `header.xml` files from the `.docx` document zip package and put them directly into the output document so that we could avoid complicated information such as various styles.

If you want to achieve this effect, you should do so:

1.Paste the part you want from the `header` or `footer` xml file (*Because my development environment is Chinese, some properties are Chinese fields, but they have little impact*)：

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:ind w:right="360" w:firstLine="720"/>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        <w:outlineLvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia" w:ascii="黑体" w:eastAsia="隶书"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia" w:eastAsia="隶书"/>
            <w:bCs/>
            <w:sz w:val="36"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>This a </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia" w:eastAsia="隶书"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:sz w:val="44"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia" w:ascii="黑体" w:eastAsia="黑体"/>
            <w:bCs/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>footer</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

`note`: you don't need the entire file, be careful not to include the topmost constraint information

2.Call poi's api to create a footer object

```java
XWPFFooter xwpfFooterHome = xwpfDocument.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
```

3.The string copied above is used as an argument to generate a `CTHdrFtr` instance object

```java
ctHdrFtrFooterHome = CTHdrFtr.Factory.parse(footerhomeString);
```

4.There is a method in `xwpfFooterHome` that sets the `CTHdrFtr` object created in `Step 3`

```java
xwpfFooterHome.setHeaderFooter(ctHdrFtrFooterHome);
```

So the full code is as follows（Note to add `xmlns:http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main` to the `<w:p>` label）:

```java
        String footerhomeString = "<w:p xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\"><w:pPr><w:ind w:right=\"360\" w:firstLine=\"720\"/><w:jc w:val=\"center\"/><w:outlineLvl w:val=\"0\"/><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint=\"eastAsia\" w:ascii=\"黑体\" w:eastAsia=\"隶书\"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint=\"eastAsia\" w:eastAsia=\"隶书\"/><w:bCs/><w:sz w:val=\"36\"/></w:rPr><w:t>中国南车集团株洲电力机车有限公司</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint=\"eastAsia\" w:eastAsia=\"隶书\"/><w:b/><w:sz w:val=\"44\"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\"> </w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint=\"eastAsia\" w:ascii=\"黑体\" w:eastAsia=\"黑体\"/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>发 布</w:t></w:r></w:p>";

        XWPFFooter xwpfFooterHome = xwpfDocument.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
        CTHdrFtr ctHdrFtrFooterHome = null;
        try {
            ctHdrFtrFooterHome = CTHdrFtr.Factory.parse(footerhomeString);
        } catch (XmlException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        xwpfFooterHome.setHeaderFooter(ctHdrFtrFooterHome);
```