# Why use the CTSectPr.Factory.parse method to parse xml labels appear nested by two <w:sectPr> tags

Tags: java, apache-poi, cpu-word

I'm going to create < w:sectPr > label in the document to section.

I have a bunch of xml characters:

```xml
        String defaultSectPr =
                "<w:sectPr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">"
                        +"<w:pgSz w:w=\"11906\" w:h=\"16838\"/>"
                        +"<w:pgMar w:top=\"1701\" w:right=\"1134\" w:bottom=\"1418\" w:left=\"1418\""
                        +" w:header=\"1185\" w:footer=\"913\" w:gutter=\"0\"/>"
                        +"<w:cols w:space=\"425\"/>"
                        +"<w:pgNumType w:start=\"1\"/>"
                        +"<w:docGrid w:type=\"lines\" w:linePitch=\"312\" w:charSpace=\"0\"/>"
                        +"</w:sectPr>";
```

And I want to use it to create  labels,So I used the following code:

```java
        String defaultSectPr =
                "<w:sectPr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">"
                        +"<w:pgSz w:w=\"11906\" w:h=\"16838\"/>"
                        +"<w:pgMar w:top=\"1701\" w:right=\"1134\" w:bottom=\"1418\" w:left=\"1418\""
                        +" w:header=\"1185\" w:footer=\"913\" w:gutter=\"0\"/>"
                        +"<w:cols w:space=\"425\"/>"
                        +"<w:pgNumType w:start=\"1\"/>"
                        +"<w:docGrid w:type=\"lines\" w:linePitch=\"312\" w:charSpace=\"0\"/>"
                        +"</w:sectPr>";

        CTSectPr ctSectPr = null;
        try {
            ctSectPr = CTSectPr.Factory.parse(defaultSectPr);
            System.out.println(ctSectPr);
        } catch (XmlException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<CTP> ctps = ctBody.getPList();
        for(CTP ctp : ctps){
            // Get the ctppr label and determine if there is a selectPr label included
            if(ctp.isSetPPr()){
                CTPPr ctpPr = ctp.getPPr();
                if(ctpPr.isSetSectPr()){
                    ctpPr.unsetSectPr();
                    // Create a selectPr label
                    ctpPr.setSectPr(ctSectPr);
            }
        }
```

But I get the results like this:

```xml
<w:sectPr>
    <w:sectPr>
        <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
        <w:pgMar w:top="1701" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1418" w:left="1418" w:header="1185" w:footer="913" w:gutter="0"/>
        <w:cols w:space="425"/>
        <w:pgNumType w:start="1"/>
        <w:docGrid w:type="lines" w:linePitch="312" w:charSpace="0"/>
    </w:sectPr>
</w:sectPr>
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with using string parsing to the CtSectPr object, so I use methods to build labels:

```java
                    CTSectPr sectPr = ctpPr.getSectPr();
                    CTPageSz ctPageSz = sectPr.addNewPgSz();
                    ctPageSz.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(11906l));
                    ctPageSz.setH(BigInteger.valueOf(16838l));

                    CTPageMar ctPageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
                    ctPageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(1701l));
                    ctPageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(1134l));
                    ctPageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1418l));
                    ctPageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(1418l));
                    ctPageMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(1185l));
                    ctPageMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(913l));
                    ctPageMar.setGutter(BigInteger.valueOf(0l));


                    sectPr.addNewCols().setSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(452l));
                    sectPr.addNewPgNumType().setStart(BigInteger.valueOf(1l));

                    CTDocGrid ctDocGrid = sectPr.addNewDocGrid();
                    ctDocGrid.setType(STDocGrid.LINES);
                    ctDocGrid.setLinePitch(BigInteger.valueOf(312l));
                    ctDocGrid.setCharSpace(BigInteger.valueOf(0l));
```

It's right:

```xml
<w:sectPr>
 <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
 <w:pgMar w:top="1701" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1418" w:left="1418" w:header="1185" w:footer="913" 
 w:gutter="0"/>
 <w:pgNumType w:start="1"/>
 <w:cols w:space="452"/>
 <w:docGrid w:type="lines" w:linePitch="312" w:charSpace="0"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

So I guess something's wrong here (I don't know if it's right):

```java
 ctSectPr = CTSectPr.Factory.parse(defaultSectPr);
```

Thanks to Axel Richter's answer, it really solved my problem, and it provided an idea for parsing the xml tag in this direction to poi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlObject.Factory.parse` methods expect parsing an object form the XML which is the **content** of the XML element (inner XML). But your `String defaultSectPr` contains the outer XML of a `CTSectPr`.

There are special `*Document` objects for some of the main root `OOXML` elements. Those can be parsed from whole document XML and only provide methods to get the single root element then. For example `CommentsDocument` provides `CTComments getComments()`.

Of course `CTSectPr` does not have such document element. But one could parse one of the parent elements of  `CTSectPr` from the outer XML of the `CTSectPr` and then get the `CTSectPr` from the `getSectPr()` method of the parent element. `CTPPr` for example is a parent element of `CTSectPr` and provides `getSectPr()`.

Example:

```
...
CTSectPr ctSectPr = null;
try {
    CTPPr ctPPr = CTPPr.Factory.parse(defaultSectPr);
    ctSectPr = ctPPr.getSectPr();
    System.out.println(ctSectPr);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```